# How do i schedule a async function for a bot using apscheduler

Tags: python, python-asyncio, apscheduler

I want to schedule a async function a using apscheduler like

if i add job to the bot and somehow i stopped running a bot after restart of the bot it should continue the function .

Like i schedules a async funtion every 3 hours and my bot stopped in middle and then i restarted bot(while restarting we will do normaly schedular.start()). I want to make it that async function to continue again without adding again .

i tried this one but it is not working

```
from apscheduler.executors.asyncio import AsyncIOExecutor
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from pytz import utc

import datetime

jobstores = {
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=database_url),
}

executors = {
    'default': AsyncIOExecutor(),
}

job_defaults = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 1
} 

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores=jobstores,
                             executors=executors,
                             job_defaults=job_defaults,
                             timezone=utc)

async def myfunc():
    print("result")

trigger_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'interval',id=55454,run_date=trigger_time)
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Think what you have is broadly correct except for how you are scheduling it. You are supplying a datetime to the job's interval. Try something like

```
scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'interval', hours=3)
```

See here for more on that method: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/interval.html

There's also `'calendarinterval'` which may be useful if you need to use dates: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/triggers/calendarinterval.html

Lastly, if `id=55454` is meant to be an argument for your function, it needs to be supplied as a list like
`scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'interval', hours=3, args=[55454])`
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job